Barcode image does not display inside a box
My barcode image does not display when I stuff the image at a given position inside a box where there are other elements in specific positions. Anybody able to point me in the right direction?
    // Generate barcode image directly onto the label canvas
    JsBarcode(labelContext, boxData.barcode.data, {
        format: boxData.barcode.format,
        width: barcodeWidth,
        height: barcodeHeight,
        displayValue: false, // Disable displaying the barcode value
        margin: 0, // Set margin to 0 to fit barcode tightly
        x: barcodeX, // Set position of barcode within the box
        y: barcodeY
    });

